# Is it possible to extend Calendar.Identifier to create a custom calendar?

Tags: swift, calendar, nscalendar

I'd like to create a swift implementation of the DDate (Discordian Date—Hail Eris!) calendar, and I'm wondering if there's a way to extend the `Calendar.Identifer` enum to include a new calendar?

I can extend `NSCalendar.Identifier` with the following code, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do the same with the `Calendar.Identifier`:

```
extension NSCalendar.Identifier {
  static let discordian = NSCalendar.Identifier(rawValue: "Discordian")
}
```

NSCalendar bridges to Calendar, but when I try to instantiate a new Calendar object using the `Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier)` init method, the new identifier doesn't show up in the identifier list. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Calendar` type in Swift is backed by `NSCalendar`, which is [Toll-Free Bridged](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010677) to/from [`CFCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfcalendar-s01).

And the documentation of `CFCalendar` clearly says:

> There is currently no API for defining your own calendars.

Swift `Calendar` does not provide such APIs neither.

---

Even if `Calendar` had such APIs, your custom calendar could not be available just providing its identifiers.

You need to implement many functionalities of `Calendar` customized for the new identifier of your own and bind the implementations to the identifier.

Again, there's no such APIs neither in `Calendar`, `NSCalendar` nor `CFCalendar`.

So, no way, you cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

[Extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) can be defined on structs, classes. Enums can be extended too with more functionality but not new cases.

The Identifier of NSCalendar is a struct defined as :

```
public struct Identifier : Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {
    public init(_ rawValue: String)
    public init(rawValue: String)
}
```

Whereas the Identifier of Calendar is an enum, and that's why it can't be extended:

```
public enum Identifier {
    case gregorian
    case buddhist
    case chinese
    case coptic
    case ethiopicAmeteMihret
    case ethiopicAmeteAlem
    case hebrew
    case iso8601
    case indian
    case islamic
    case islamicCivil
    case japanese
    case persian
    case republicOfChina

    @available(OSX 10.10, iOS 8.0, *)
    case islamicTabular

    @available(OSX 10.10, iOS 8.0, *)
    case islamicUmmAlQura
}
```

And it's not possible to have a certain enum extend and inherit the cases of another enum.

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar.Identifier` is an `enum`, while `NSCalendar.Identifier` is a struct. `enum` cases are immutable once the `enum` is declared, so you cannot add any new cases to `Calendar.Identifier` and hence cannot achieve your goal.

The built-in identifiers of `NSCalendar.Identifier` are bridged to the `Calendar.Identifier` enum, but whatever you add from Swift as an extension to `NSCalendar` cannot be bridged to `Calendar`.